# Dropdown selector to change color of DIV using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

What I need is a simple color picker (max 6-8 color) so the user can choose a color for an event that will be entered in a calendar.

I have tested several jQuery colopicker plugins and none have worked well in my project.

Either they are too complex (like Farbtastic) or are simple but don't run on the most recent version of jQuery.

So I decided to provide a good ol' dropdown menu with a list of colors

```
<select id="evt_color"> 
<option value="#3366CC">Blue</option> 
<option value="#E070D6">Fuchsia</option> 
<option value="#808080">Gray</option> 
<option value="#4bb64f">Green</option> 
<option value="#ed9d2b">Orange</option> 
<option value="#FF9CB3">Pink</option> 
<option value="#EA4A4A">Red</option> 
</select>
```

This works well. But I would like to give the user some feedback on the color they choose, before submitting the form.

I wonder if somehow we could create a small square DIV next to the dropdown, and have its `background-color` change to the value of the selected color `onChange`, via something like `getElementById` or other method. By default, the first color would be selected (Blue).

Anyone have suggestions for this? jQuery or raw JS suggestions are welcome!

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#evt_color").change(function() {
        $("#someDiv").css("background-color", $(this).val());
    }).change(); // trigger change event so div starts out with a colour
                 // on page load
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNgYm/)

Comment: thanks so much for putting this together - it's a very nice little piece of code

Comment: OK, you gave a great answer but could you please just add an info on how to have this selection remembered for each visitor?
I would actually like users to be able to change background color of several divs but so that the color is remembered throughout the blog i.e. that they don't have to change color when opening another post or page. Could you please help with that? Thanks.